# Why myLocation still not changes after run setMockLocation [kotlin]

Tags: android

this is my code, runing with android studio, Kotlin Compose.
on my print success set to new location moc

`New GPS Location: Location[gps -6.180965,106.833078 hAcc=1.0 et=+6d2h4m53s61ms mock]`

but myGPS not move on new GPS Location.
please help me to solve, why is this happening

using Google Maps in a Compose application and trying to set a mock location. not trigger the "My Location" button or the blue dot immediately.

using Google Maps in a Compose application and trying to set a mock location. not trigger the "My Location" button or the blue dot immediately

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.location.provider.ProviderProperties
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.PlayArrow
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.FabPosition
import androidx.compose.material3.FloatingActionButton
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBar
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarDefaults
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.maps.android.compose.CameraPositionState
import com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMap
import com.google.maps.android.compose.MapProperties
import com.google.maps.android.compose.Marker
import com.google.maps.android.compose.MarkerState
import com.google.maps.android.compose.rememberCameraPositionState
import com.lord_oyen1.ui.theme.Lord_oyen1Theme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val locationPermissionCode = 123
    private var ismock = 0
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private var indonesia = LatLng(-6.1687086, 106.7537442)

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    private val mockLocationRunnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            getLastLocation(-6.180965, 106.833078)

            // Repeat the process after a certain delay (e.g., 5000 milliseconds or 5 seconds)
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        handler.removeCallbacks(mockLocationRunnable)
    }

    private fun requestLocationPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            ),
            locationPermissionCode
        )
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    private fun setMockLocation(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        val locationManager = getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        val accuracy = 1
        val gpsProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER
        val locationGps = Location(gpsProvider)
        locationGps.latitude = latitude
        locationGps.isMock = true
        locationGps.longitude = longitude
        locationGps.accuracy = accuracy.toFloat()
        locationGps.time = System.currentTimeMillis()
        locationGps.elapsedRealtimeNanos = System.nanoTime()

        try {
            // Throws IllegalArgumentException if a provider with the given name already exists
            locationManager.addTestProvider(
                gpsProvider,
                false,
                false,
                false,
                false,
                false,
                true,
                true,
                ProviderProperties.POWER_USAGE_HIGH,
                ProviderProperties.ACCURACY_FINE
            )
        } catch (ignored: IllegalArgumentException) {
        }

        try {
            // Throws IllegalArgumentException if no provider with the given name exists
            locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(gpsProvider, true)
        } catch (ignored: IllegalArgumentException) {
            locationManager.addTestProvider(
                gpsProvider,
                false,
                false,
                false,
                false,
                false,
                true,
                true,
                ProviderProperties.POWER_USAGE_HIGH,
                ProviderProperties.ACCURACY_FINE
            )
        }

        try {
            // Throws IllegalArgumentException if no provider with the given name exists
            locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(gpsProvider, locationGps)
        } catch (ignored: IllegalArgumentException) {
            locationManager.addTestProvider(
                gpsProvider,
                false,
                false,
                false,
                false,
                false,
                true,
                true,
                ProviderProperties.POWER_USAGE_HIGH,
                ProviderProperties.ACCURACY_FINE
            )
            locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(gpsProvider, true)
            locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(gpsProvider, locationGps)
        }


        Log.d("MockLocation", "New GPS Location: $locationGps")

        cameraPositionState.position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(LatLng(latitude, longitude), 10f)
    }

    private lateinit var cameraPositionState: CameraPositionState

    @Composable
    private fun MyMapComponent(indonesia: LatLng) {
        cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
            position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(indonesia, 10f)
        }

        GoogleMap(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
            properties = MapProperties(isMyLocationEnabled = true)
        ) {
            Marker(
                state = MarkerState(position = indonesia),
                title = "Indonesia",
                snippet = "Marker in Indonesia"
            )
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    fun onFabClick() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            try {
                // Start setting mock location periodically
                ismock = if (ismock == 0) {
                    handler.postDelayed(mockLocationRunnable, 0)
                    1
                } else {
                    onDestroy()
                    0
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // Handle the exception
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        } else {
            // Request location permissions
            requestLocationPermission()
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    private fun getLastLocation(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                    // Handle the retrieved location
                    location?.let {
                        // Now you can use latitude and longitude for your mock location or other purposes
                        setMockLocation(latitude, longitude)
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    // Handle the exception
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
        } else {
            // Request location permissions
            requestLocationPermission()
        }
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        requestLocationPermission()

        setContent {
            Lord_oyen1Theme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Scaffold(
                        topBar = {
                            TopAppBar(
                                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
                                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                                    titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                                ),
                                title = {
                                    Text("Small Top App Bar")
                                }
                            )
                        },
                        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
                        floatingActionButton = {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                                FloatingActionButton(onClick = ::onFabClick, shape = CircleShape) {
                                    Icon(Icons.Filled.PlayArrow, "Floating action button.")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ) { padding ->
                        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(padding)) {
                            MyMapComponent(indonesia)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```